# How to translate order status on API response

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

Is there any way how to translate order status on API response

```
“https://test.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders “.

{
“status”: “processing”,
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to use this in PHP, we need to translate it to a format that PHP understands. To do this, we can use the json_decode() function.

```
 $json  = '{"key":"value"}';

 // Translate into an object
 $obj   = json_decode( $json );

 // Translate into an array
 $array = json_decode( $json, true );
```

Comment: Where i have to do that ?

Comment: @user10539558, What you want to translate, pass  variable name .